# The provided value is not a valid RFC-2822 date

Tags: curl, bigcommerce, rfc2822

I have been testing BigCommerce API calls,

Firstly i tried orders.json call, and i did got proper reply.

But when i added date range parameters ie min_date_created and max_date_created, it gave me error.

I am testing it using PHP cURL, Following was the URL:

```
https://test.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/orders.json?min_date_created=Thu, 16 May 2013 07:23:55 +0000&max_date_created=Sat, 18 May 2013 18:29:59 +0000
```

And following is the error i am getting:

```
[status] => 400
[message] => The field 'min_date_created' is invalid.
[details] => stdClass Object
(
[invalid_reason] => The provided value 'Thu,' is not a valid RFC-2822 date.
)
```

Can any one tell me where i went wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: Try escaping your spaces? With %20 or +

Comment: Thanks! i urlencoded the parameters and now i get proper reply.

Comment: I turned my comment into an answer, since it ended up being, well, an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment promoted to answer after it was correct:

You need to rawurlencode your parameters.

*edit*changed urlencode to rawurlencode, so that spaces are properly encoded to %20 as RFC, as opposed to +'s*

Comment: urlencode() didn't work, But rawurlencode() worked properly in php.
Thanks!